# How put apartment gem to work with ActionCable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

My Rails 5 app uses ActionCable and I have tenants (using the [apartment gem](https://github.com/influitive/apartment)). But ActionCable does not see the apartment middleware, so does not set the tenant.

Does anyone have a way to make this all work together?

Comment: I put a $25 reward for resolving the issue. https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [apartment-sidekiq](https://github.com/influitive/apartment-sidekiq) gem for ease-of-use and to achieve the same result instead of using `ActionCable`.

Comment: My application is totally based on ActionCable. Thank you for your help.